# SSIS Data flow failing - calling a Sybase ASE stored procedure using temp tables

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, oledb, sap-ase, ssis-2012

I have been battling with a SSIS task (2012), which has a series of Data flow tasks run in series.

In particular, there is one data flow task that is failing at the Data Source stage.  I am Calling a Sybase ASE (15) stored procedure, using the OLE DB driver.  This stored procedure is called via a "Command Via Variable" call.

What is happening is the stored procedure is failing at the end of the Pre-Execution phase, with an "Unable To Retrieve Column Information From The Data Source" error message.

The failure only occurs when I run this from the SQL server (2014) that I have deployed the process to.  It appears to run OK in my dev environment (Visual Studio 2012).

The only clue I have at the moment points to the ASE Stored Proc.  I have commented out a whole bunch of updates and other proc internal Temp Table populates and it all works fine.  I start randomly adding them back and the process fails - there appears to be no rhyme or reason.....

Has anyone come across this issue before?  Is there any setting on either SSIS, SQL Server or ASE that I could set that might assist?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why it'd behave differently between 2012 and 2014 but I'm guessing the ASE driver differs between the two installs? That said, the general approach is to have as your first statement in the stored procedure a "fake" resultset. `IF (NULL = NULL) BEGIN SELECT 1 as Col1, 'A' AS Col2 END` this allows SSIS to validate the metadata even though that statement could never logically be executed. There's duplicates of this question in the SSIS tag, just don't have the cycles to look for it yet

Comment: Thanks - yes, I have seen that trick.  Was trying to avoid it, but I will give it a try.

Comment: One other thing - I thought that this only worked at the validation stage?  Or is it going to make a difference at the Pre-Execute stage as well?

Comment: OK, getting closer.  I have tried the fake result set and that hasn't worked.  I have, though, observed that the failure is after a reasonably consistent time frame at a nominal 35 seconds.

This appears to point to the CommandTimeout custom option for the source connection, which I had left this at 0(infinite).

I have now set it to 60 seconds, but it still keeps failing at 35 seconds.  I have also changed the connection timeout to 120 seconds, with no change.

So, this now tends to point at some time out value somewhere at the SQL Agent level.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: And its all working - ASE driver incompatibility between my Dev environment and the server I have deployed to has caused havoc....  Once all the drivers were in line, everything has worked out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above, the issue came down to driver incompatibility between my dev environment and the SQL server that I deployed the SSIS project to.

In short, My dev environment is using the ASE 15.7.0.1260 suite of drivers.  The SQL server that I was deploying to had the ASE 15.7.0.501 suite of drivers installed.

Once the SQL server had its drivers updated, all has started working faultlessly.